# Accessing an array with Pointer this way?

Tags: c

Its basically passing an array to a function via pointer. Then it prints out each element in the array. Im trying to understand a very specific line of pointers since my class has never done a example like this before. After finishing intro I never encountered this in the pointers topic, hence why Im confused. thank you.

```
main( )
{
    inta[3][4] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4,
        5, 6, 7, 8,
        9, 0, 1, 6
    } ;
    display ( a, 3, 4 ) ;
    show ( a, 3, 4 ) ;
    print ( a, 3, 4 ) ;
}


display ( int*q, introw, intcol )
{
    inti, j ;
    for ( i= 0 ; i< row ; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < col ; j++)
            printf("%d ",*(q+i*col+j)); // THIS is the line Im trying to understand

        printf( "\n" ) ;
    }
    printf("\n" ) ;
}
```

Comment: *(p+i) is equal p[i]

Answer (score 2):

Let's view the 2D array as a single array:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
-------------------------------------------------
  ^
index 0
```

And if we take a closer look at the expression `(q+i*col+j)`:

```
q + (0 * 4) + 0 = 0th index
q + (0 * 4) + 1 = 1st index
q + (0 * 4) + 2 = 2nd index
q + (0 * 4) + 3 = 3rd index
     ^        ^
     i        j
```

After the first row has been printed, `i` becomes 1:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
-------------------------------------------------
                  ^
               4th index

q + (1 * 4) + 0 = 4
q + (1 * 4) + 1 = 5
q + (1 * 4) + 2 = 6
q + (1 * 4) + 3 = 7
                  ^ indices
```

As you can see, this points to the next row.

`i` becomes 2:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
-------------------------------------------------
                                  ^

q + (2 * 4) + 0 = 8
q + (2 * 4) + 1 = 9
q + (2 * 4) + 2 = 10
q + (2 * 4) + 3 = 11
                  ^ indices
```

And so on. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`*(q+i*col+j)` is equivalent to `q[i*col+j]`.

When using pointer arithmetic, adding a number x to a pointer evaluates to an address x bytes times the size of the pointer type ahead of the initial address (offset).

Comment: When using pointer arithmetic, adding a number x to a pointer evaluates to an address x bytes times the size of the pointer type ahead of the initial address (offset). This is read-only evaluation and not assignment like `p += 1;`. "Moves the pointer" - not very accurate.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer with your (better) phrasing

Comment: Also is q+i being multiplied by col+j or are we dereferencing col+j? This is causing me extreme confusion.  thank you.

Comment: @ChrisRosado Operator precedence applies, so it ends up as `q + (i*col) + j`